# How to setup Sendlog in Child BU for Grandchild BU Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

Is it possible to Setup a Sendlog on the Child BU, where Sendlog data of the grandchild BU is being captured?

If so, what is the procedure to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

There are four options for sendlog, and this is not a supported configuration

- log ALL sends at the Enterprise (top level BU) sendlog
- log ALL sends at the BU sendlog
- log only sends with the sendlog check box to the Enterprise sendlog
- log only sends with the sendlog check box to the BU sendlog

each configuration has to be configured by support, and each MID can have their own configuration